# how to put a banner with link in the company's emails

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, outlook, outlook-addin, exchange-server

First, sorry but my English isn't good

We need develop an app that lets an admin user manage banners, and these banners could be placed in the footer-body of the company's emails.

In the company they use Outlook and we work with **C# .NET 3.5**

I think in something like a listener than could catch the emails in some event on the Exchange Server, or something like an agent that could be installed in the clients, but i don't know about the implementation possibilities.

The banners' info could be stored in a DB and the admin could use a web interface.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Comment: yeah, i did it with VSTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i worked with VSTO

[VSTO Outlook Embed Image MailItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196160/vsto-outlook-embed-image-mailitem)

[VSTO Outlook ItemSend with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186277/vsto-outlook-itemsend-with-c)

thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

here's a couple starting points

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;317327

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;317680

sorry, running out the door, thought I would get you started

Comment: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30878241/adding-disclaimer.aspx "The problem that you will run into is that this only works for SMTP
communications - mails from Outlook are ignored with this solution. To fix
this, you'll need to create a second virtual SMTP server on your Exchange
server and route all outgoing mails from the first SMTP server to the second
one and from there to the internet. Install the OnArrival script on the
second virtual SMTP server."
Another solution? something like a Exchange Service installed on the Exchange Server? Thanks anyway

Comment: @EstebanLopez ~ Sorry bout that, was about to turn off the computer and saw the title, wanted to at least give you something to read. Yeah, the only way that _I_ know of is to EITHER mandate a common signature block in Outlook (one company I used to work for did this, just an HR policy), and the only other way is to use Exchange (or Google Mail for companies would probably do the same, by "use Exchange" I mean configure it at the SMTP server level) and do it for all outbound mail.

Comment: it's possible do something like this (http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;317327) with C#?

Comment: @EstebanLopez ~ yes, if you're going to be using Exchange 2007 or later I believe so. Have you found anything else about this? Also, have you asked this on ServerFault? I'm sure they have an instant answer for you.