# VSTO Outlook ItemSend with C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I'm trying to add a string in the end of an Outlook email's body with VSTO

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
    }

    void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
            mail.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            mail.Body += "My Sample Text";
            mail.Save();
        }
    }
```

When i run with F5 my code from VStudio, **the app isn't stopping in my breakpoints and the emails do not contain the added line**

What I can do about it?

**Note**: I'm working with VS2008 and Outlook 2007

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry...

The problem was i've to close my outlook and restarted with F5.

If someone have this same issue, now you know