# Adding hidden bcc to Outlook mail with c#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm using POP for mails and I want to inform one of my company mails when a message is sent by one of the users. I want it hidden so they cannot delete it. There are solutions but not free and not suitable for every version of Outlook.

Is there a short way to code it in c#, like an office add-in?

Example: [VSTO Outlook ItemSend with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186277/vsto-outlook-itemsend-with-c-sharp)

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.ItemSend += new
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(
    Application_ItemSend);
}

void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
        mail.BCC += ";Name Surname<name.surname@tld.com>";
        mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
        mail.Save();
    }
}
```

This code worked a couple of times but now it is not working.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Hitting F5 from Visual Studio..

Comment: What happens when you step through your code? Does Application_ItemSend get hit?

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/02/06/outlook-itemsend-sendbutton-events/) will help you.

Bottom line: hook the [`ItemSend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationevents_11_event.itemsend.aspx) event.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy Add-in Express is not necessary to hook the ItemSend event. Visual Studio is, of course. Is that what you're complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

Do not add to the BCC property, use something like the following.

```cs
var recip = mail.Recipients.Add("\"Name Surname\"<name.surname@tld.com>");
recip.Type = OlMailRecipientType.olBCC;
recip.Resolve();
```