# Outlook MailItem embed images not shown in sent mails

Tags: c#, image, email, outlook, office-interop

I have the following code to embed images to `Outlook MailItems`:

```cs
private void ReplaceImageIds()
{
   foreach(var image in Image.GetImagesFromText(HTMLBody))
   {
      var imageTag = $"<img src \" cid:{image.Id.ToString()} \"/>";

      var attachment = _mailItem.Attachments.Add(image.FilePath, OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "");
      attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001F", "image/png");
      attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", image.Id.ToString());

      HTMLBody = HTMLBody.Replace($"ImageId={image.Id.ToString()}", imageTag);
   }
}
```

That works just fine. The images are shown when i receive the e-mail - but just there.

When i take a look at my sent-mails folder in outlook the images are just shown like this:

[image: Wrong shown image in outlook]

Does anyone have an idea why they are shown like this and can help me to fix that?

I'm confused about that because the images are shown when i receive the e-mail.

Mail is send like this:

```cs
public Boolean Send()
{
   // Check if all properties are set.
   Validate();

   try
   {
      var oApp = new Application();

      var oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

      oNS.Logon();

      _mailItem = oApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem) as MailItem;

      // Set To, CC and BCC.
      AddRecipients();

      // Replace images.
      ReplaceImageIds();

      if (Body != null)
         _mailItem.Body = Body;

      if(HTMLBody != null)
         _mailItem.HTMLBody = HTMLBody;              

      _mailItem.Subject = Subject;

      // Set account to send.
      SetSendingAccount(oApp);

      // Add attachments.
      AddAttachments();

      _mailItem.Send();

      oNS.Logoff();

      return true;
   }
   catch (System.Exception ex)
   {
      Utils.LogException(ex, "Could not send email.");
      throw new System.Exception("Could not send email.", ex);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your code you replaced in the html with `ImageId={picture.Id.ToString()}` what is picture? picture doesnt seem mentioned in your code everywhere else its image

Comment: picture is image - issue in refactoring. Edited question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSTO Outlook Embed Image MailItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196160/vsto-outlook-embed-image-mailitem)

Comment: Your problem seems to be you arent adding the attachments with their Ids

Comment: No. I've shorten the code for this question. And i just forgot to change this string. Also the images are shown when i receive the e-mail. Just not in "sent-mails" folder.

Comment: It is really hard to help when the actual problem is not listed..

Comment: The actual problem is in the question. "When i take a look at my sent-mails folder in outlook the images are just shown like this:". Means: The e-mail is sent with images and the images arrive and are shown in the folder of the receiver. But they are not shown in the folder of my sent e-mails.

Comment: But you arent giving us how to recreate this.. the code is incomplete, and constantly changing when pointing out issues with it..

Comment: First of all the code is not constantly changing. I corrected one spelling. And I posted everything of the code that is needed to reproduce this. The rest has no connection to the problem.

Comment: Are the images shown correctly in the Sent Items folder after you restart Outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this issue right now.

For those who have the same problem here's my new method where i add the image references:

```cs
private void ReplaceImageIds()
{
   foreach (var image in Image.GetImagesFromText(HTMLBody))
   {
      var imageTag = $"<img src = \"cid:{image.Id.ToString()}\"/>";

      var attachment = _mailItem.Attachments.Add(image.FilePath, OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 0, image.Name);

      attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001F", "image/jpg");
      attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", image.Id.ToString());

      HTMLBody = HTMLBody.Replace($"ImageId={image.Id.ToString()}", imageTag);

      }
   }
```